# Multiple SNMP Agents with nsoftware dll

Tags: c#, snmp

I use the SNMP tool from nsoftware (or IP*Work!, it's the same) named SecureSNMP V8 .net Edition (C#) and I try to run multiple Snmp agent on a standalone.

Nsoftware give a sample agent and documentation but i didn't fine anything helpful.

If someone know this tool and how to create and run simultaneously multiple agents, can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I just have to set the localhost property of an snmpAgent BEFORE activate it and the modification can be seen only after activation.

Multiple agent can run simultaneously if they have same port, but with differents ip addresses.

Sorry to disturbed you with this easy question.

Comment: That is correct, by default, the component will use the ip address 0.0.0.0 if you do not set the LocalHost property. So the solution is to manually set the LocalHost to different ip addresses and then both agents will be able to be bound to the same port.